# Node js express - Simple Login example

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, ejs

this is index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get("/", function(req, res, next) {
    res.render("login", {
    });
});

router.post("/", function(req, res, next) {
    var id = req.body.id;
    var pw = req.body.pw;

    if(id == "test" && pw == "1234") {
        res.render("loginSuccess");
    }
    else {
        res.render("loginFail");
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

this is login.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
    <head>
        <meta charset = "UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action = "http://localhost:3000/" method = "post">
            ID : <input type = "text" name = "id"><br>
            PW : <input type = "text" name = "pw"><br>
            <input type = "submit" value = "Connecting Server...">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

This code is working well by using post in postman...

but It does not work at localsite when I insert "test" and "1234".

Where can I fix it?

Comment: Please add details of what error you are getting.Most problems can be discovered if you check the logs. If you are sending request from browser, check the console log. If you are seeing errors in console, search for them. Ask only if you don't find an answer for your problem.

Comment: I found the answer. <form action = "localhost:3000" method = "post"> modify to <form action = "/" method = "post"> and it works... Thanks for your comment :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to send the data as raw on postman and if it works bodyparser is the reason for it. If you want to use x-www-form-urlencoded, your bodyparser should has that option enabled

Comment: I found the answer.

<form action = "http://localhost:3000/" method = "post">

modify to

<form action = "/" method = "post">

and it works...
Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

You need the [body-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) middleware, to read the names from `req.body`

Install the package with npm, and import it in the top of your index.js file

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
```

Then tell body parser to parse the post route as a form request, by changing the post route to the following

```
router.post("/", bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }), function(req, res, next)
```

For a more detailed explaination, see the readme for [body-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) on npm

Comment: I already include body-parser.
But I found the answer.

<form action = "http://localhost:3000/" method = "post">

modify to

<form action = "/" method = "post">

and it works...
Thanks for your help :)